# Copy from Range A to Range B and don't overwrite existing date in B

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy from Range rngA lets say A1:F70 to Range rngB H1:M70
But Range B already might contain some data.
How should i copy the data over?

Should i check every possible cell and only copy the cell analog to it over?
using `rngA.Copy rngB` would just overwrite everything

I also don't want to shift the current cells down. Only overwrite the empty ones.

I tried to do my own function, but it currently just totally fails to even execute it.

```
RangeCopyNoOverwrite (rgLastWorkWeek, rgThisWorkWeek)
```

---

```
Public Sub RangeCopyNoOverwrite(ByVal rngSrc As Range, ByVal rngDest As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Cursor = xlWait
    Dim destCell As Range
    Dim srcCell As Range
    Dim breite As Long
    Dim hoehe As Long

    breite = rngSrc.Columns.Count
    hoehe = rngSrc.Rows.Count
    
    For I = 0 To hoehe
        For J = 0 To breite
            Set srcCell = Range(Cells(rngSrc.Row + I, rngSrc.Column + J), Cells(rngSrc.Row + I, rngSrc.Column + J))
            Set destCell = Range(Cells(rngDest.Row + I, rngDest.Column + J), Cells(rngDest.Row + I, rngDest.Column + J))
            If IsEmpty(destCell) = True Then
                srcCell.Copy destCell
            End If
        Next J
    Next I
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Cursor = xlDefault
End Sub
```

Comment: Well my solution was to not pass the range as a value over. somehow this just fails for me. So global ranges are used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub RangeCopyNoOverwrite(rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range)
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Cursor = xlWait
    For r = 1 To rngSrc.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To rngSrc.Columns.Count
            If IsEmpty(rngDest.Cells(r, c)) Then
                rngSrc.Cells(r, c).Copy rngDest.Cells(r, c)
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Cursor = xlDefault
End Sub
```